# How to add an eps file with transparency in beamer slides

Tags: beamer, eps

I use kile to edit tex files. I need to include an eps file (logo) with a part that is transparent. When I use:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{../img/logo_dark.eps}
```

It just prints the path of the file. If I add [dvips] then I get the error "Cannot determine size of graphic ..."

Here is what I have:

```
\documentclass[serif,mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, epsfig, xspace}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\usepackage{bmpsize}

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage[normal,tight,center]{subfigure}
\setlength{\subfigcapskip}{-.5em}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\title{Introduction}
\author{StackEx}

\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{../img/servers.jpeg}}

\date{}


\logo{%
  \makebox[0.95\paperwidth]{%
     \includegraphics[scale=0.17]{../img/logo_dark}%
    $\qquad$ \hyperlink{questions}{\beamergotobutton{?}}
    \hfill%
    %\includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{cs_logo}%
  }%
}

\institute{Unilateranensis}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Who}

\begin{center}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.38]{../img/diva.jpeg}
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Edit: If I convert jpeg files to eps, then it works.

Is there any way to include image files as they are or do I have to convert all images to eps?

Comment: latex/dvips can not include jp(e)g files so you will get the bounding box error if you process this with latex/dvips it should work with pdflatex. however never use `epsfig` package and you should only very rarely need `epstopdf` and should not need it here.

Comment: it is not clear what you mean by eps with transparent background as transparency is a pdf feature that isn't natively support in PostScript.